# Migration from Angular 4.4.0 to Angular 5.2.0 cause error in server side rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am migrating my angular application from `4.4.0` to `5.2.0` which supports server-side rendering.

While running the command in angular (v5) `npm start` i am getting this error

```
src/server.ts(5,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'.
```

Also, I check `dist` folder which doesn't contain the same file.
I think there is something to change in configuration to fix it which I am missing.
Did anyone face the same issue?

server.ts contains :

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const compression = require('compression')

const PORT = 4000;
let forceHttps = false;
const livehoststring = '-';
const livehost = '-';
const staticlivehost = '-';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

app.use(compression());

const template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

After reading some articles seems I have to import `AppServerModuleNgFactory` from a different location. but I am unable to find the exact location.

Comment: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ if you use this site it will tell you what you need to change/update

Comment: @mxr7350 Thanks so much for this awesome website, but I did make all the changes already.

Comment: Can you try `npm build` first and check whether folder has specific file or not? I guess there could be some error in build(just a guess).

Comment: @PankajParkar is there any difference between `ng build` and `npm build` ? anyways thanks, but I sort out the problem I was facing (as mentioned below as answer) but now stuck at new error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem by just replacing the `AppServerModuleNgFactory` import path in `server.ts` as following :

```
const {  AppServerModuleNgFactory } = (module as any).exports;
// import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
```

By replacing this as above your `npm start` command will works fine.

(PS: But after that I got new error on run )

> Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined

[Solution for this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811623/5043867)