# Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined while npm start

Tags: angular

I am working on the application which supports server-side rendering with angular cli (1.7.3).

While running the command `npm start` build will create successfully but while running application on the server it throws error showing

> Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined

I assume the error is coming from `server.ts` file where I am importing `AppServerModuleNgFactory` like this :

```
const {  AppServerModuleNgFactory } = (module as any).exports;
// import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
```

PS: This was working fine with angular `4.4.0` but not with `5.2.0`

Please let me know if needed more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this probelm after houres of googling.

Actually the problem is in ng5 they had changed some configuration while build like removal of ngfactory etc.
so `server.ts` is unable to find `AppServerModuleNgFactory` module while server side rendering.

so I had to change the location from new path if not found like this

```
const {  AppServerModuleNgFactory } = (module as any).exports;
....
some code 
....

if ( typeof(AppServerModuleNgFactory) == 'undefined') {
  const { AppServerModuleNgFactory } = require('../dist/out-tsc/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory');
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
  .then(html => callback(null, html));
} else {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
  .then(html => callback(null, html));
}
```

Comment: @Pradeep Jain Can you please describe it a bit as I don't have this file '../dist/out-tsc/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory', I have file './dist/server/main.bundle'

Comment: If you don't have this one you can try it by using `'./dist/server/main.bundle'` this path in your configuration to get the module.

Comment: @PardeepJain i have tried both  by using '../dist/out-tsc/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory' and  './dist/server/main' as I haven't bundle file generated but it still not working

i am working with angular 6

Comment: For Angular6 they have changed the dist folder structure i guess.